# Bypassing AuthenticationDomainService on Silverlight WCF RIA Services

Tags: c#, silverlight, forms-authentication, wcf-ria-services

I'm building a quite simple content management system that does not require such an extended and complicated user system. I'd like to be able to manage user sessions myself in a simple fashion.

I was wondering if there is something I could use to simplify my life. Is there any kind of session classes I could simply handle myself instead of playing with the whole user/group/role system?

I just want to build a simple system with user/password nothing more.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with the Business Template then, and just build a standard Silverlight Project or Navigation Project and just incorporate whatever you want with custom DomainContext objects.

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing. But the question is : how to manually handle user sessions? Is there any way of creating user sessions programatically without using the whole MS system?

Comment: That really depends on how far you want to take it. For example, you could just have a DB method that creates a GUID for a user at login (in an SQL table), and have it live as long as the login session. Or, you could actually use ASP session keys like they suggest here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightASPNetSessions.aspx